# GDAL 1.11 no vector support?

Tags: c, linux, gis, gdal, ogr

I was trying to look at the OGR api in GDAL, and was following the tutorial here: http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html.  I kept getting an undefined reference to pretty much everything.  I've installed from source the latest version (1.11) on my linux distro from here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource.  Looking through the header file, specifically in gcore/gdal.h, I see for example that GDALOpenEx is not there, nor is it in the version before that.  It is, however, in the subversion repository.  So, what gives?

Comment: What is your actual question?  You seem to be asking three of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `GDALOpenEx` function for GDAL 1.11. You are looking at documentation for GDAL 2.x.

The documentation for 1.11 is found at http://gdal.org/1.11/

Or, you can make the documentation for the version you are using locally, e.g.:

```
make docs
sudo make install-docs
```

Then view them locally from your web browser, e.g.:

```
chromium /usr/local/doc/ogr/ogr_apitut.html
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is just weird to me, that the documentation on their website is for the subversion repository, and not the current stable source release.